# Getting Items in Cart

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2, cart, custom

I've tried many methods over the web including here too but still I can't seem to be able to get items currently in cart, tried checkout sessions cart model, cart helper nothing works, It sometimes work randomly (using same code), anyone have an idea about how can I get items in cart to place them in my custom module view.

Magento 2.2.4

Update :

Mahran/Whatsapp/Block/Display.php

```
<?php
namespace Mahran\Whatsapp\Block;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->checkoutSession = $session;
       }



public function yourFunction()
{
    echo 'Executed';
    $items = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($items as $item) {

      echo " Product Name :- ".$item->getName();
      echo " Product Name :- ".$item->getSku();
      // You can use $item->getData(), it'll return all the information of cart item 
   }

   return $items;
}


}
```

And I am calling the function in the view phtml file.

Mahran/Whatsapp/view/frontend/templates/whatsappview.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * @var \Mahran\Whatsapp\Block\Display $block
 */
$items = $block->yourFunction();
$string = "Items";
foreach($items as $item){
  $string = $string."*".$item['sku'];
}
?>


    <h1>Checkout via WhatsApp</h1>

   <form id="whatsappForm" action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="GET">
    <h3>Please enter your information to confirm order via WhatsApp</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullname">Fullname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Enter name" required="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Enter address" required="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter city" required="true">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="message" id="message" value="<?php echo $string; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="whatsapp">
  <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="order">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it's working for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to get cart items.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
) {
     $this->checkoutSession = $session;
 }

public function yourFunction()
{
    $items = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    $cartItems = [];
    foreach($items as $item) {
      $cartItems[] = [
       'name' => $item->getName(),
       'sku' => $item->getSku(),
       ];
      // You can use $item->getData(), it'll return all the information of cart item 
   }
   return $cartItems;
}
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I've added this to the page block but still no luck what is the best practice to apply this code ?

Comment: where you want cart items? I mean is there any specific page?

Comment: Yes, I am placing the cart items in a view I have in user frontend.

Comment: can you please let me know where you add this code, you can update it in your question.

Comment: Updated the question with requested info.

Comment: You need to return what you need in your phtml file. I thought you know about this. anyway I updated my answer as well.

Comment: Of course I know about this, the problem is it's returning an empty array to the view file.

Comment: Have you updated the code as per my answer and please post your phtml file where you are calling this function

Comment: Yes, I did and included the view file in the question for you.

Comment: It'll definitely work for you, make sure yourFunction is calling. Please check it at your end once.

Comment: Added echo debug statement in the function and its executing fine but still not showing products I have in cart and this is driving me crazy tbh.

Comment: I hope you already update answer and returning from that function what you need. If you are not returning anything then you can't get any details.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lmry28

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code and check it **test.log** file in `var/log` folder.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
) {
     $this->checkoutSession = $session;
 }

public function yourFunction()
{
    $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuoteId();
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $itemsIds = [];
    if(!empty($quoteId)){
      $cartItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
      foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
        $itemsIds[] = $cartItem->getProduct()->getId();
      }
      $logger->info('If function call');
    } else {
      $logger->info('Else function call');
    }
    return $itemsIds;
}
```

Comment: 2018-11-26T16:52:59+00:00 INFO (6): Else function call

Comment: If possible observer result sent via whatsapp message?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    function getitems(){
       $quote = $this->cartObj->getQuote()->loadByCustomer($customerId);
       $items = $quote->getAllItems();
       $a=array();
       $i=1;

       foreach($items as $item) {
          $a[$i]['ProductId'] = $item->getProductId();
          $a[$i]['ProductName'] = $item->getName();
          $a[$i]['ProductSku'] = $item->getSku();
          $a[$i]['ProductQty'] = $item->getQty();
          $a[$i]['ProductPrice'] = $item->getPrice();
          $i++;            
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**add below code in your file**

```
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $_objectManager,
    )
    {
        $this->_objectManager       =   $_objectManager;
    }

    function yourFunction(){
    $cart = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')

    // retrieve quote items collection
    $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

    // get array of all items what can be display directly
    $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

    // retrieve quote items array
     $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    foreach($items as $item) {
         echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
         echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
         echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
         echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
         echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
         echo "<br />";            
      }
    }
```

I hope it help...!!!

Comment: Tried this didn't work too, it seems impossible to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by replacing

> \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context

with

> \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context

in your __construct method.

Please remove generated/code files after updating the dependency.

Not verified but should work.

**Updates**

Update mentioned files with given code below:

> Mahran\Whatsapp\Block\Display.php

```
<?php
namespace Mahran\Whatsapp\Block;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function getCartItems()
    {
        $items = null;
        try{
            $items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems(); 
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->_logger->debug($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $items;
    }
}
```

> Mahran/Whatsapp/view/frontend/templates/whatsappview.phtml

```
<?php
$items = $block->getCartItems();
$string = "Items";
if($items != "null")
{
   foreach($items as $item){
     echo $string = $string."*".$item->getSku()."<br />";
   }
}
?>


    <h1>Checkout via WhatsApp</h1>

   <form id="whatsappForm" action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="GET">
    <h3>Please enter your information to confirm order via WhatsApp</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullname">Fullname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Enter name" required="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Enter address" required="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter city" required="true">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="message" id="message" value="<?php echo $string; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="whatsapp">
  <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="order">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Remove generation files and check with it. Let me know if still it doesn't work.

Comment: I still can't seem to get the items in the page I can see the items in minicart but they dont appear on the page.

Comment: Check my updated answer and try with it.

Comment: @Mostafa Mahran Did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

All of your solutions would work just fine, the problem was full page cache which was affecting the current session make sure to add `cacheable=false` in the block layout xml file.